# Adding GeoTIFF image to GeoServer: failed to create reader from file

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to add a GeoTiff-file to GeoServer through adding a raster data source, but whenever I try to add my file, I get the error 'Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///mnt/hgfs/VMSharedData/newmaps/download.tiff and hints null'.
I suspect it's something with the information of the file, but I can't find out what. I've ran gdalinfo on it and this was the output:

http://pastebin.com/DQqremJt

To confirm that the problem is within the file, I've tried downloading another GeoTiff file from TrueMarble, and that file did indeed upload correctly.
This is the gdalinfo output from the TrueMarble file:

http://pastebin.com/23pajuri

Does anyone know what the error might be? Does my file lack any data?
I'm afraid I don't know much about GIS in general, so any help people here could provide me would be very valuable.

UPDATE -- EXTRA INFORMATION:
I couldn't open the incorrect file with GIMP, but it opened just fine with QGIS.
The GeoServer log says "Projection not supported" when I try to upload the incorrect GeoTIFF-file.

Comment: Does the tif display correctly elsewhere,  for example in GIMP?

Comment: It doesn't. The correct image opened just fine, but the malfunctioning one caused Gimp to generate "too many" error messages. The first 3 I could see were akin to "Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered".
I guess this means that my GeoTIFF-files are incorrect. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure that the specific CRS is supported by geoserver? I mean is the CRS listed in SRS List.

Comment: I don't think it is. I tried editing it to a different one, but that required an EPSG code. I didn't know which EPSG code that would be so I just went for 4326, which caused for an incorrect projection - is there any way to get the required EPSG code from my metadata?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the sinusoidal projection that makes the trouble. These links tell how to add sinusoid projection as a custom projection into Geoserver and Geotools
http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/modis-sinusoidal/geoserver/
https://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05993.html

However, discussion is three years old and the method to add the projection is not simple. I suggest to ask from geoserver-users list if adding the sinusoid projection is easier with the current Geoserver versions.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have two files (tif+tfw), which is some subset alternative to pure GeoTIFF (only one tif file keeping spatial data inside), then try to choose WorldMapImage instead of GeoTIFF when choosing store, I had this problem and this was good solution.

Answer (score 0):

turn the logging level to "geotool development level",you will find the error "FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user". you can solve the error by edit the configuration file(pg_hba.conf) to add a new record for "host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0              md5"